# Laravel sum up field in pivoting table

Tags: laravel, sum, pivot

I have 3 tables, *products*, *orders* and *order_product*, the 3rd one is a pivoting table that contains a field named *product_quantity* to record product quantity for the order relating to the corresponding product. Now I want to calculate the total sold products during a given period, I fetched orders like so:

```
Order::whereBetween('created_at', array($start_date, $end_date))->where('status', $order_status_completed)->get()
```

And got stuck next, I surely don't want to iterate each fetched order to sum *product_quantity* up, for that's one heck of a way to kill performance as far as I know, any way I can do it by simply using ->sum('product_quantity')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement gets you the set of orders you're interested in.  You can then use the list of the ids to query the order_product table.  Something like:

```
// get the orders
$orders = Order::whereBetween('created_at', array($start_date, $end_date))->where('status', $order_status_completed)->get();

// get an array of the ids
$orderIds = $orders->lists('id');

// sum the order_product.product_quantity for the related orders
$total = DB::table('order_product')->whereIn('order_id', $orderIds)->sum('product_quantity');
```

If you don't care about the order objects themselves, you can just directly get the ids:

```
// get the order ids
$orderIds = Order::whereBetween('created_at', array($start_date, $end_date))->where('status', $order_status_completed)->lists('id');

// sum the order_product.product_quantity for the related orders
$total = DB::table('order_product')->whereIn('order_id', $orderIds)->sum('product_quantity');
```

If you want to use a subquery instead to two separate queries, you can do something like:

```
$total = DB::table('order_product')
    ->whereIn('order_id', function($q) use ($start_date, $end_date, $order_status_completed) {
        $q->select('id')
            ->from((new Order())->getTable())
            ->whereBetween('created_at', array($start_date, $end_date))
            ->where('status', $order_status_completed);
    })
    ->sum('product_quantity');
```

Comment: Exactly what I've been looking for! Thanks!